# How to set p:carousel width to 100%?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I need that carousel assumes width of the page.If i set width to 100%, nothing changes:

```
  <p:carousel numVisible="1" effect="easeInStrong" circular="false" style="width:100%">
```

Also, if I set itemStyle="width:100%", the width changes to 32000 px.

Ideas?

Comment: try to make code snippet of your code

Comment: I not found an online tool to make it. @YahyaEssam, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: ok share your full code so may we can help

Comment: I added the code in this jsfiddle, but it cannot run online. https://jsfiddle.net/g1wh9j1m/

Comment: It is about the client-side html code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

The **p:carousel** element was inside of a **p:panelgrid**.
Removing the external **p:panelgrid** solved the width problem.
Also, we updated primefaces version to 6.0 and added the attribute *responsive="true"*, and now it is responsive..

```
<p:carousel numVisible="1" effect="easeInStrong" circular="true" responsive="true">
```